# Why does C++ automatically rounds float

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal, rounding, cin

I have a code like this...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    float num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << num;

return 0;
}
```

Input: 256.1024

Output: 256.102

Why does C++ automatically rounds my float to three decimals?

Comment: Not "rounded": printed with a precision unsuited to your need.

Comment: `cout <<` rounds to 6 digits by default (the number includes digits before the dot too).

Comment: `float` doesn't even store "decimals".  Your input - whatever it may be - is converted to a float approximation.  This approximation is close enough to match the first 6 or 7 decimal digits.

Comment: `cout << setprecision(4) << fixed << num;`

Comment: The value actually stored for that input is 256.102386474609375. Check out what is happening to your bits [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you have documentation specifying that it would make a good answer. If there's a statement from the standard it would make a *fantastic* answer.

Comment: Short answer, not mentioned at the duplicate - you rarely want the full precision of a floating point number because it exposes the oddities of binary representation. A rounded result is more useful most of the time.

Comment: @MarkRansom The defaults are set by [`std::basic_ios::init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init) (the same table is listed in the C++ standard under `[basic.ios.cons]`).